# How can I add process parameters using sbt-native-packager?

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

How can I add process parameters using sbt-native-packager configuration? I want to add the options for redirect process stderr to file? To have the result like that:
`sudo -u app bash -c "app >>/var/log/app/stderr.log 2>&1"`

I use sbt-native-packager 1.2.0-M5 for build deb package with `JavaServerAppPackaging, JDebPackaging, SystemdPlugin, UpstartPlugin` the exception in logs, only in stderr. Also I must delete app pid manually after crash and if it exists, then I have error in stderr.

My plugins.sbt:

```
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("sbt", "sbt-plugin-releases")

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.8-netty-4.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.2.0-M5")

addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.8.2")

addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.sbt" % "sbt-javaagent" % "0.1.1")

libraryDependencies += "org.vafer" % "jdeb" % "1.3" artifacts (Artifact("jdeb", "jar", "jar"))
```

my build.sbt:

```
...
debianPackageDependencies in Debian ++= Seq("postgresql-9.5 (>= 9.5.1)")

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala, JavaAgent)

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val akkaVersion = "2.4.10"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4.1208",
  "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc" % "2.4.0",
  "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc-config" % "2.4.0",
  "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc-play-initializer" % "2.5.1",
  "org.flywaydb" %% "flyway-play" % "3.0.1",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-contrib" % akkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % akkaVersion,
  "io.dropwizard.metrics" % "metrics-core" % "3.1.2",
  "io.dropwizard.metrics" % "metrics-jvm" % "3.1.2",
  "org.coursera" % "dropwizard-metrics-datadog" % "1.1.4",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % akkaVersion % Test,
  "com.relayrides" % "pushy" % "0.8",
  "com.relayrides" % "pushy-dropwizard-metrics-listener" % "0.8",
  "org.eclipse.jetty.alpn" % "alpn-api" % "1.1.3.v20160715" % "runtime",
  ws,
  specs2 % Test
)

resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases/"
resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

javaOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Dlogger.resource=logback-test.xml")

scalacOptions in Universal ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-notailcalls")

javaOptions in Universal ++= Seq(
  "-J-server",
...
)

...

import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.systemloader._
// UpstartPlugin for ubuntu 14.04, SystemdPlugin for ubuntu 16.04
enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging, JDebPackaging, SystemdPlugin, UpstartPlugin)

requiredStartFacilities := Some("datadog-agent.service, systemd-journald.service, postgresql.service")

javaAgents += "org.mortbay.jetty.alpn" % "jetty-alpn-agent" % "2.0.4" % "dist"
```

ps I found a workaround, in ubuntu 16.04 I can use journald to collect all the logs in the system.

Comment: Can you please provide some context? Which plugins are enabled, which version are you using, what package format are you building and which systemloader ( if any ) have you configured?

Comment: @Muki, done. Tell us what is missing, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for updating the question with all relevant information. There are a couple of things here.

#### Only one Systemloader plugin

You enable `SystemdPlugin` and `UpstartPlugin`. If it works, it only works by accident. No version of native-packager was designed to support multiple systemloader for a single package type in a single build module.

The solution is to create sub modules with the relevant systemloader enabled.

#### Logging to stderr

You are right regarding `systemd`. It provides facilities to capture the log output of your process. If you like you can add your findings to the native-packager documentation ( there is a [systemd plugin section](http://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/latest/archetypes/systemloaders.html#systemd) ).

The `upstart` support in native-packager is rather simple. There weren't a lot of requeset as Ubuntu is switching to `systemd` and you can always fallback to `systemv`. Which brings me to the solution to your problem.

You can use the `SystemVPlugin`, which supports a [daemon_log_file](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/resources/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/archetypes/systemloader/systemv/start-debian-template#L42-L48). The [systemv documentation](http://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/latest/archetypes/systemloaders.html#systemv) provides you with the necessary details.

cheers,
Muki

Comment: All answers boil down to the fact that now you can not customize the parameters of the process. It may be necessary to add this functionality?

Comment: If you can provide this function for Upstart we would accept a pull request. But since upstart is basically replaced by systemd we won't add this on our own.